# How to show the Android "contact pane"?

Tags: contacts, android, android-contacts

I'm working on my first Android app, and wondering what call I can make to show this "contact pane":

[image: Contact Pane]

I am of course, referring to the little pane with the contact's photo, name, and the action icons underneath.

As a related question... what is the official name for this little popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is QuickContact and there are some helper methods in android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact you can use including:

```
showQuickContact(Context context, View target, Uri lookupUri, int mode, String[] excludeMimes)
```

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html

Comment: You both gave the same answer, but I'm awarding you the points, to help you build your rep up. Thanks, and cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the other answer until I had typed mine up and referenced it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [showQuickContact()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html). As you may have guessed the name of this widget is QuickContact dialog.